# Wordpress plugin configuration will not launch

Tags: wordpress, configuration

I have installed CiviCRM on my wordpress site and I am able to activate the plugin. When I go to the configuration page, I get a blank screen and nothing happens. No errors are generated but I can't move forward. Any suggestions?

Edit: I am hosting the site at Arvixe. The server error logs are blank.

Comment: It's not clear which configuration page you're referring to, please update the question to clarify?

Comment: If you're getting a blank screen, there's probably an error in your web server's log that can tell you what's up. Without more information about your hosting environment, I don't think there's much more that could be said.

Answer (score 1):

After activating CiviCRM, did you run the installer?
See instructions here at http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installing+CiviCRM+for+WordPress